# How can I start my jquery function only on input change, not on page load?

Tags: jquery

I have a select box, which autoselects automatically the appropriate value of my input field. It works very well:

```
<input id="count" value="2.00" type="number">

<select class="autoselect">
  <option data-number="1000000000000" selected value="dog">dog</option>
  <option data-number="2000000000000" value="horse">horse</option>
  <option data-number="4000000000000" value="cat">cat</option>
  <option data-number="5000000000000" value="bird">bird</option>
</select>
```

Here is the query code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count = 1000; 
    $('#count').change(function () {
            var that = parseInt($(this).val()*Math.pow(count, 4), 10);                          
            $('.autoselect option:gt(0)').each(function () {
                $(this).prop('disabled', ($(this).data('number') < that))
                .prop('selected', ($(this).data('number') >= that && $(this)
                .prev().data('number') < that));
            })
            if (that <= $('.autoselect option:eq(1)').data('number')) $('.autoselect option:eq(1) ').prop('selected', true);
            $('select.autoselect option[data-number=0]').prop('disabled', false);       
        }).change()
}
```

What I want to achieve is actually a simple thing. On page load, "dog" should always be selected. Only by changing the input, my script should start to work. But it is already selecting "horse" on page load, even if I wrote the function on input change.

Comment: you wrote code for catching `change` event and why are you triggering it on page load  `}).change()`. As you are triggering change , your dropdown is getting updated

Comment: @JSantosh I removed `.change()` but still the function is starting on page load

Comment: reproduce the issue in fiddle , then someone can see whats going on

Comment: I had another function in my code which still had `.change` at the end. So now it is working fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second .change() function is triggering this event on page load. jQuery event functions without callbacks are event triggers. Just remove second .change() at end of your code.